# FindAsync CancellationToken fail

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, cancellation-token

The code below has a `for` loop to test that the cancellation token is working when attempting to retrieve a record from the Activity table:

```
public class Handler : IRequestHandler<Query, Result<Activity>>
{
    private readonly ReactivitiesContext _context;
    private readonly ILogger<Activity> _logger;

    public Handler(ReactivitiesContext context, ILogger<Activity> logger)
    {
        _context = context;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<Result<Activity>> Handle(Query request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);
                _logger.LogInformation($"{i} second(s) have elapsed");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Cancellation was done");
        }
        return Result<Activity>.Success(await _context.Activities.FindAsync(
            new object[] { request.Id }, cancellationToken));
    }
}
```

However when cancelling the request (through Postman), it does not cancel.  Instead, the request returns the correct "Activity" object, and the for loop runs its course, even though I cancel after 2-3 seconds have elapsed.  See logs:

```
info: Domain.Activity[0]
      1 second(s) have elapsed
info: Domain.Activity[0]
      2 second(s) have elapsed
info: Domain.Activity[0]
      3 second(s) have elapsed
info: Domain.Activity[0]
      4 second(s) have elapsed
info: Domain.Activity[0]
      5 second(s) have elapsed
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 6.0.6 initialized 'ReactivitiesContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.6' with options: None
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (35ms) [Parameters=[@__get_Item_0='?' (DbType = Guid)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT TOP(1) [a].[Id], [a].[Category], [a].[City], [a].[Date], [a].[Description], [a].[Title], [a].[Venue]
      FROM [Activities] AS [a]
      WHERE [a].[Id] = @__get_Item_0
```

The `FindAsync` cancellation approach used closely follows the guidance provided in this GitHub issue:  https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12012

Here they advise to pass the `FindAsync` params as an array, followed by the cancellation token.

Can anyone see what needs to be corrected in order for the cancellation token to work?

Thank you in advance.

Edit 1/11/23:
Thank you to Nikolay, who solved my issue with his last comment from 1/10.  My controller was not passing the cancellation token - here is the corrected controller, which has corrected the issue and 'cancel' is now working:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetActivity(Guid id, CancellationToken token)
{
    return ResultHandler(await Mediator.Send(new Details.Query { Id = id }, token));
}
```

Nikolay - if you post this as an answer, I will mark this as the answer.  In the meantime, I upvoted all of your comments.  Thank you again for your much appreciated insight!

Comment: I didn't quite understand your issue. When you cancel your request in postman do you get your "Cancellation was done" message in logs, but request to db through EF still continues (meaning, that cancelationToken was canceled correctly, but EF didn't process it correctly) or you don't get this message in log meaning cancelation of request in postman does not work with your server http requests infrastructure and cancelation tokens there?

Comment: As a side note, the `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` is superfluous. The `await Task.Delay` that follows does also the same internally.

Comment: Hello @Nikolay, and thank you for your comment.  After reading your response I realized my post was not clear.  I edited by clarifying exactly what comes back when I click "cancel" in Postman, including the log from VS Terminal when running dotnet watch run.

Comment: So the problem seems to be somewhere in passing cancelation token from http request to your Handler. Do you use asp.net core or some other server framework? can you show your code for this request (like controller or whatever your use) and how you call your handler class there?

Comment: I think this post also has value in highlighting that  FindAsync(request.Id, cancellationToken)  would not work, the 12012 link provides the answer... This is how it should be done ...  FindAsync(new object[] {request.Id}, cancelationToken);